# Default variables in class with g++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have a class which should only ever be initialized in a certain way. As part of the error checking, I have a `bool quality` which I want to have a default value of zero unless the correct constructor is called (which then checks the arguments to see whether it has been called correctly).

```
class CParameters {
    private:
        bool quality = 0;
    //Plus some additional code
};
```

gives me

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
bool quality = 0;
               ^
```

Alternatively:

```
class CParameters {
    private:
        bool quality;
    public:
        CParameters;
};

CParameters::CParameters
{
    quality = 0;
}
```

gives me the following error:

```
error: declaraion does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
CParameters;
^
```

Alternatively2:

```
class CParameters {
    private:
        bool quality;
    public:
        CParameters();
        bool good();
};

CParameters::CParameters()
{
    quality = 0;
}

bool CParameters::good()
{
    return quality;
}
```

and then calling it

```
CParameters CLI;
CLI.good();
```

gives this error:

```
error: request for member 'good' in 'CLI', which is of non-class type 'CParameters()'
```

**EDIT: The second alternative is correct. The reason CParameters() is a non-class is that I'm too dumb to actually compile parameters.cpp while compiling the other files.**

Comment: Pay attention to the message you get. This is a C++11 feature which is supported by G++ in C++11 mode, so turn on C++11 mode.

Comment: That's going to be my last-case solution, but I remember initializing variables in classes well before c++11

Comment: Are you sure that what you remember isn't initialising *static* variables in-class?

Comment: BTW, I deleted previous comment about `good()` removed because the comment you got on that on one of the answers is more appropriate.

Comment: @hvd: I'm not so sure any more. Is this simply a case of me misremembering it? I thought for sure you could have default values in a class #doesn'tUseC++VeryOften

Answer (score 1):

For your "alternatively" you have missed some brackets:

```
class CParameters {
    private:
        bool quality;
    public:
        CParameters();
    //            ^^^
};
```

The error says:

> error: declaraion does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
>   CParameters;

Without the brackets it's just a type, which declares nothing. With the brackets it's a prototype for a constructor.

It might make more sense, if you want to check the *correct* constructor is called to just have one correct constructor, so the compiler finds errors, rather than having to check at runtime.

....**Edit**....
You also need brackets in the definition:

```
CParameters::CParameters()
//                     ^^^^
{
    quality = 0;
}
```

Comment: @medivh Your edit isn't clear but I can see another error now: see my edit

Comment: CParameters::good() is missing the return type (bool). should be `bool CParameters::good()`

Comment: @medivh The sample you post here must be code that gives the error you tell us about otherwise we can't help

Answer (score 1):

like doctorlove mentioned, you miss () in the constructor.

You cannot assign default values in class. you can only do it in the constructor.
If I understand you correctly, what you want is something like:

```
CParameters::CParameters () : quality(false)
{
//your checking
quality = true;
}
```

Or, have your ctor throw if the parameters are wrong.

Comment: What you say applies to C++03, not to current C++.

Comment: Obviously, you are correct., however, given the error:
 non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
I assumed he does not use c++11. nevertheless, I should havee mentioned it